# Enable ws-security for proxy service

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

Currently we have enabled ws-security in wso2 esb using policy file and role based authorization using Active Directory.

We would like to transition some of these services to wso2 api manager and implement the same security model.

How do we secure these APIs (that are facing web service client and not the backend web service) using ws-security on api manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To secure the APIs on API manager you can follow [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Working+with+Security) guide. It provides various methods that can secure the APIs. Further if you need to implement role based authorization to the APIs in API manager you can refer to [this tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/use-of-wso2-api-manager-to-validate-fine-grained-policy-decisions-using-xacml/).

Hope this helps.